# Is it possible to include multiple .ui files in one main.ui file?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I have a Qt app with multiple QWidgets. I would like to create for each QWidget an .ui file to be able to reuse the same .ui file in different places and to have a simple structure for main.ui. Because now I have a big .cpp file with all slots and signals for all QWidgets and it is not so easy to work. I have not found a solution yet and I would like to know if it's possible. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: If you make each of the ui files a widget you can create a .ui file that references your promoted widgets.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. But to be able to promote them I have to create also the header file, right? @drescherjm
I am asking you because I am not using QtCreator, I use Visual Studio and I have to create manually the .ui files, headers and .cpp files.

Comment: Yes you create a header and implementation file for each of these widgets. I use Visual Studio also but with CMake instead of the addon.

Comment: Yes, with CMake also. Ok, I understood. Thank you !! @drescherjm

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know including one such file into another is not supported but I might be mistaken.

If you want to use multiple `.ui` files the general practice is to use `QUILoader`, which allows loading different such files at runtime.

Frankly I would just go for implementing all this by hand. You can then separate/group the different widgets in whichever way you want.

Comment: In the meantime I found the "promote to" feature and I think this is the solution to link DockWidget.ui in a special place in the main.ui file.